# How to delete an SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I want the ability to delete an SQLite database by a button press in my app. However when I put the function for deleting the database I get compiler errors. How can I use the function?

Problem is how to use this method; ourContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
do I define the method in the DBcontroller class that also defines DATABASE_NAME or do i define it in the other class where I want to call the method with onclick listener.  How can I use this deleteDatabase() method without errors in my application?

I put deleteDatabase inside of deleteDB() method and want to call this method in an onclick listener of the other class called SQLiteExample

Here is the class that has the function to delete the database defined in it.

```
public class DBcontroller {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="persons_name";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER="persons_number";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME="sampledb";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="peopleTable";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private DbHelper ourHelper;
    private final Context ourContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    // DbHelper methods
    }

    // function to delete database defined here
    public void deleteDB(){
    ourContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

And here is the second class called SQLiteExample where I want to call the deleteDB method from the other class to delete the database called, DATABASE_NAME

```
public class SQLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    public void onClick(View arg0){
        switch(arg0.getId()){
            case R.id.deleteDatabase:

            // want to put code to call delete database here
            // so database is deleted with a button click
```

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: for "context" message is "context can not be resolved", and for "DATABASE_NAME" message is "cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: Have you put this function inside class? Because, from your code seems it is outside the DbHelper class. Just check that once

Comment: i just put it inside the DbHelper class like this,  Context context;
  public void deleteDB(){
   context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
  }

Comment: So compiler errors solved?

Comment: I had to make a local Context context; for it.   after putting the method inside of the DbHelper class I tried to call it from the other class onclick listener like this, deleteDB();  but i get the compiler error that the method is undefined for the SQLiteExample class.  i am thinking about making it a static method but that is causing more errors

Comment: You should call it as DBcontroller obj = new DBcontroller(); 
obj.deleteDB(); Because your method is in DbController class. Not in SQLiteExample class itself

Comment: that removed all the compiler errors,  but the database does not get deleted.  it is still there, even after restarting the android device.

Comment: Are u sure the method was executed? And was there any error in logcat?

Comment: found the problem that I did not register the onclick listener that is why the button push was not deleting the database.  Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To delete database use this,

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

Comment: problem is that I am getting red underline compile errors for both "context" and "DATABASE_NAME"   for the method context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

Comment: Edit your question and tell what is your exact problem..I think if you apply simple programming logic you can fix the error.. JUST THINK

Comment: it works now.  I thought the problem was more complex and found the problem was simple and easy to fix.   I did not think i could fix it so easily.

Comment: Happy to hear that and never give up your self....just try and try you will get it